# Shelosha Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred and three?

### ?שלושה ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 303.

Lazy gematria on this one is not worth approaching.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred and two entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: July 3rd? [15ch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The year 5757 was the last year of cycle # 303 of the 19 year moon cycle.

Answer (score 3):

[In October 1926, 303 Jews left Poland for Eretz Yisrael.](http://archive.jta.org/article/1926/11/10/2763963/303-jews-leave-poland-for-palestine-in-october)

Answer (score 2):

[In the year 5303/1543](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1543) (which is 303 לפ"ק), R' Chaim Vital was born.

Comment: Any source? The Wikipedia article you link to says only 1543, and [the rabbi's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayyim_ben_Joseph_Vital) does the same, citing only [a book](http://books.google.com/books?id=B2o8vqvrQOcC&pg=PA2) that does the same again. Maybe he was born between _Rosh Hashana_ and the end of the Julian year?

Comment: [This](http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380648/jewish/Rabbi-Chaim-Vital.htm) article gives the Hebrew year as 5303, but it does say circa.

Answer (score 0):

[Reportedly](http://www.sztetl.org.pl/en/city/lesko/), in a 1705 plague in [Lesko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesko), 303 Jews died.